# find a linear function $f(x,y) = ax + by + c$ which minimizes the total square error

Tags: optimization, regression-analysis

find a linear function $f(x,y) = ax + by + c$ which minimizes the total square error

$E(a,b,c) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (f(x_{i},y_{i})-z_{i})^{2} $

where $(x_{i},y_{i})$ are $n$ given distinct points and $z_{1}......z_{n}$ are $n$ given real numbers

Comment: A first step would be to take the derivatives w.r.t. $a,b,c$ and find the points where they're all equal to zero.

Comment: Do you know any paper which talk about it?

Comment: Ever heard of normal equations?

Comment: Normal equation of Gauss

Answer (score 1):

Let $\textbf{x} = (x,y,1)^T$ and let $X = (\textbf{x}_1, \cdots, \textbf{x}_n)$ be the data matrix (each column corresponds to one sampling point). Let also $\textbf{z} = (z_1, \cdots, z_n)^T$ be the measurements. You're trying to find a vector $\textbf{v} = (a,b,c)^T$ which minimizes $g(\textbf{v}) = \frac{1}{2}\|X^T\textbf{v} - \textbf{z}\|_2^2$. It follows: 
\begin{align}
g(\textbf{v}) = \frac{1}{2}\langle X^T\textbf{v}, X^T\textbf{v}\rangle - \langle X^T\textbf{v},\textbf{z}\rangle + \frac{1}{2} \|\textbf{z}\|_2^2. 
\end{align}
Setting the gradient equal to 0 yields $\nabla g(\textbf{v}) = XX^T\textbf{v}-X\textbf{z} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \textbf{v} = (XX^T)^{-1}X\textbf{z}$ (these are called the normal equations). Note that the inverse is well defined, since you assume that the points  are distinct.

You might want to read a bit more about linear regression and/or normal equations.

Comment: Thx Jean-Luc Bouchot

Answer (score 0):

Using BranchedOut's suggestion
and writing it out
explicitly.

$\begin{array}\\
E(a,b,c) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (f(x_{i},y_{i})-z_{i})^{2}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (ax_{i}+by_{i}+c-z_{i})^{2}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{\partial E(a,b,c)}{\partial a} 
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2x_i(ax_{i}+by_{i}+c-z_{i})\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (2ax_i^2+2bx_iy_{i}+2cx_i-2x_iz_{i})\\
&= 2a\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2+2b\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_{i}+2c\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iz_{i}\\
\end{array}
$

Defining
$r(u)
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_i
$,
$s(u)
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_i^2
$,
and
$t(u, v)
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_i v_i
$
where $u$ and $v$
are any of
$x, y, z$,
this becomes
$\dfrac{\partial E(a,b,c)}{\partial a} 
= 2as(x)+2bt(x, y)+2cr(x)-2t(x, z)
$.
For extreme values
of $E(a, b, c)$,
this requires.
$as(x)+bt(x, y)+cr(x)-t(x, z)
=0
$.

This is the first of
the normal equations
for $a, b$, and $c$.

Doing the same thing for
$\dfrac{\partial E(a,b,c)}{\partial b} 
$
and
$\dfrac{\partial E(a,b,c)}{\partial c} 
$
will get the other two equations.

Solving them
will get the values
of $a, b,$ and $c$.